# Sending push notification to specific user by tag in OneSignal

Tags: php, onesignal

I am new to Onesignal, and I am testing to send push notifications to my app users.

All users are included into OneSignal segments and I am using these segments to send push notifications to all users included in the needed segment.

But now I need to send a push notification to a specific user. Each user has a tag called id_usuario and a value for it.

This is how am I sending the push notifications to all users from a segment:

```
$content = array(
        "en" => 'El usuario '.$username.' ha creado el spot '.$nombre_spot
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "....",
        'included_segments' => array($segmento), //,array('AND'),array('App users'),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'small_icon' =>"ic_push",


        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic ...'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

What should I change to send the push notification only to a user based on his id?

Onesignal tag is "id_usuario" and the value will be saved in variable $id_user.